# Textillate CSS animation not fully working with jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I have added a textillate effect to text on a second jquery mobile page. When I click on the page 2 button in the navbar, the animation works correctly when page 2 is displayed. When I click on the page 1 button in the navbar followed by clicking on page 2 button, the text is displayed without animation. I presume there is javascript code to re-initialize the effect but I am at a loss what it is.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>put title here</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.lettering.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.textillate.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="animate.min.css"/>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#ffffff">
<!-- Start of page-->
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
   <div data-role="navbar" id="nbar3" data-iconpos="left">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#page1" class="ui-btn-active">Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#page2">Page 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div> <!-- end of navbar -->
</div><!-- end of page -->
<!-- Start of page-->
<div data-role="page" id="page2">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#page2').on('pagecreate', function() {
       $('.anim0').textillate({
      });
    });
  </script>
  <div data-role="navbar" id="nbar4" data-iconpos="left">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#page1">Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#page2" class="ui-btn-active">Page 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div> <!-- end of navbar -->
  <div class="anim0" data-in-effect="fadeInLeftBig" style="font-family:Arial; font-size:34px;     color:#000000; position:absolute; top:37px; left:196px;">hello</div>
</div><!-- end of page -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In *Textillate* documentation, it is not mentioned if you can *reinitialize* same text again. However, you can simply *destroy* it and then *reinitialize* it.

To destroy it, you need to first save text in a `var` and then remove *Textillate data* stored into that target div by using `.removeData()`. And then replace all *animated elements* within target div with original text. You can use either `pagecontainerbeforehide` or `pagecontainerhide` to do the aforementioned steps.

To *reinitialize* it, just call `.textillate()` on `pagecontainerbeforeshow` or `pagecontainershow`.

```
$(document).on('pagecontainerbeforeshow', function (e, data) {
    /* initialize */
    $('.anim0', data.toPage).textillate();
}).on("pagecontainerhide", function (e, data) {
    /* store text */
    var text = $(".anim0 ul li", data.prevPage).text();
    /* remove data and add original text back */
    $(".anim0", data.prevPage).removeData().html(text);
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/0tjtfsbv/)**